# How can we use expression inside debounce in ng-model-options

Tags: angularjs

Instead of using the hardcoded value 3000 in debounce. Can we use constants and access using expression? Tried the below the code but not working. Kindly help.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 3000, 'blur': 0} }"

ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': '{{banking.timeout}}', 'blur': 0} }"
```

Comment: just banking.timeout does not work? `{default: banking.timeout, blur: 0}`

Comment: while giving just banking.timeout, it is taking the default debounce value and not the value mentioned in the constants (3 seconds).

Comment: angular default value is 500ms, so 3000 is the one you set it but you want to set it to banking.timeout later. And according to source code of angular, it does not do $observe on ngModelOptions, which mean, its one-time setting, you have to set it before template is rendered, IMO.

Comment: @YOU : How to set it before the template is rendered. Can you kindly suggest?

Comment: in controller, synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression without the `""`.

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="model.value"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': debounceDuration, 'blur': 0} }">
```

Controller:

```
angular
 .module('app', [])
 .controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.model = {
    value: ''
   };

   $scope.debounceDuration = 500;
 });
```

I have created a JSBin with he implementation: https://jsbin.com/riforo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: using $scope its working, checked the JSbin which you provided, but I am working using 
    var banking = this; 
    banking.timeOut = 3000;
 So configured accordingly but its taking the default value only.Can u check once this as well?

Comment: OK. Let me try using the controller as syntax

Comment: Since the `controllerAs` syntax is just a variation of using the controller variables, this will work. See the updated JSBin: https://jsbin.com/riforo/2/edit?html,js,console,output